# Uploading Media FTP VS HTTP(Multipart

Tags: android, http, ftp

i have an application that uploads media files (image,video) , i will need to upload the media files which the minimum size approximately >30MB , what is the optimal and fastest way to upload the media files , **FTP or through HTTP ( Multipart )?**

Answer (score 0):

optimal != fastest. faster would be FTP (a little bit), optimal would be HTTP multipart upload, because it gives you nice option of retransmission lost piece of data, ftp will just close connection and may need making new one and uploading from the beginning. We are talking in the context of Android, mobile data transmission isn't as reliable as fixed connection, so multipart will behave "more practical"

Comment: While I do not disagree that HTTP might be better – FTP allows transfer resumption too. And retransmitting with HTTP requires new connection too.